# How to update/insert contact image in android's contact list programmatically?

Tags: android, image, photo, android-contacts

I am working on an application in which i've to update contact details of a contact.I've updated all the details of contacts from my application but unbale to update the image of contact from gallery or from camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using ContactsIntegration project available on github.Its a nice and proper example to update contacts details.Thx

Comment: get it here [contactIntegration](https://github.com/gwoodhouse/ContactContractSample/blob/master/ContactsIntegration/src/com/woodhouse/example/activity/ContactsIntegrationActivity.java)